# Applying APIM policies based on client

Tags: jwt, access-token, azure-api-management

I want to apply some APIM policies based on the clientId from which the request is coming from.
I want to validate the tokens coming from a particular client for certain claims and not for rest of the clients.
I am trying it by various ways, but none works and makes the policy return 500 internal server error for each request.
Can anyone help me know what am I doing wrong or how can this be done.

```
 <set-variable name="authToken" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","Bearer").Split(' ').Last())" />
        <choose>
<when condition = "@(((Jwt)(context.Variables["authToken"])).Claims["appid"].Contains("{{particularAppClientId}}"))">

        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
            <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/some_tenant_id/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>{{clientId}}</audience>
                <audience>{{ResourceId}}</audience>
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>https://sts.windows.net/some_tenant_id/</issuer>
            </issuers>
            <required-claims>
            <claim name="roles"  match ="any">
                <value>Task.Write</value>
                <value>App.Setup</value>
            </claim>
            </required-claims>
        </validate-jwt>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
            <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/some_tenant_id/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>{{clientId}}</audience>
                <audience>{{ResourceId}}</audience>
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>https://sts.windows.net/some_tenant_id/</issuer>
            </issuers>
        </validate-jwt>
        </otherwise>
        </choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try getting and setting the token as follows instead?

```
context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization",string.Empty).Split(' ').Last().AsJwt()
```

The rest of the implementation, conditional, etc, looks valid to me as it aligns with the official sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policies/authorize-request-based-on-jwt-claims